# JavaScript function isn’t being called (Firebase project)

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, momentjs

When I fill out the table and hit submit everything updates except the two calculated values, tRemainder and minTillTrain. Pulling my hair out...

I can’t even get a window.alert() to show when I call the update() function, which makes me think the function cant be called. I would appreciate any feedback here. The only other file I have is a .html page, a basic web page with a table and an input form. You enter the required data and it adds and entry to the table, and the last two columns of each row are calculated values

edit: I think the issue is I'm never reaching the $('tbody tr') portion of the code. I can get console.log() and window.alert() everywhere but there

```
// $('#train-time').mask('00:00');
// $('#time-freq').mask('0#');
//initialize firebase
var config = {
    apikey: "AIzaSyCxuLoAiSG_d69-43Tj43hLX6lgzg6Dq04",
    authDomain: "train-schedule-451ab.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://train-schedule-451ab.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "train-schedule-451ab",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: 559747835158,
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var database = firebase.database();

// Current Time
var updateTime = function () {
    var currentTime = moment();
    $("#current-time").html(moment(currentTime).format("H:mm:ss"));
};
setInterval(updateTime, 1000); // every second

//sumbit for new train
$("#btn-add").on("click", function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    //pushing newly submitted train data into firebase
    database.ref().push({
        name: $("#train-name").val().trim(),
        destination: $("#train-destination").val().trim(),
        starttime: $("#train-time").val().trim(),
        frequency: $("#time-freq").val().trim()
    });
    $("#train-name").val('');
    $("#train-destination").val('');
    $("#train-time").val('');
    $("#time-freq").val('');
});
database.ref().on("child_added", function (snapshot, prevChildKey) {
    // // generate remove button
    // var btn = $("<button>");
    // btn.addClass("trash-btn");
    // btn.attr("data-key", snapshot.key);
    // var i = $("<i>");
    // i.addClass("material-icons");
    // i.text("delete")
    // btn.append(i);
    // btn.click(remove);
    // generate table elements for new train
    var $tr = $('<tr>').append(
        $('<td>').text(snapshot.val().name),
        $('<td>').text(snapshot.val().destination).addClass('destination'),
        $('<td>').text(snapshot.val().starttime).addClass('starttime'),
        $('<td>').text(snapshot.val().frequency).addClass('frequency'),
        $('<td>').addClass('arrival'),
        $('<td>').addClass('min-away'),
    ).appendTo('#train-table');
    update();
});
//do an update function every minutes
var date = new Date();
setTimeout(function () {
    setInterval(update, 60000);
    update();
}, (60 - date.getSeconds()) * 1000);

function update() {
    $('tbody tr').each(function () {

        var frequency = $(this).find('.frequency').html();
        var firstTime = $(this).find('.starttime').html();

        // First Time (pushed back 1 year to make sure it comes before current time)
        var firstTimeConverted = moment(firstTime, "hh:mm").subtract(1, "years");

        // Current Time
        var currentTime = moment();

        // Difference between the times
        var diffTime = moment().diff(moment(firstTimeConverted), "minutes");

        // Time apart (remainder)
        var tRemainder = diffTime % frequency;

        // Minute Until Train
        var minTillTrain = frequency - tRemainder;

        // Next Train
        var nextTrain = moment().add(minTillTrain, "hh:mm");

        $(this).find('.arrival').html((nextTrain).format("hh:mm"));
        $(this).find('.min-away').html(minTillTrain);

    });
}
```

Comment: Any errors in your browser console?

Comment: I don’t see any - console just stays empty. Warns me about being in a non production Firebase environment

Comment: Is this an ordering problem? Will it help to define `update()` before using it in `setTimeout()`?

Comment: @alttag I don't think so, because I moved the entire `update()` function directly after my Firebase configuration information and still had the same problem